# Insert a TextBox and set the formula

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA for Excel 2007, I want to add a textbox to the active sheet and set its formula to a cell. My problem is that the `AddTextbox` function returns an object with typename `Shape`, not `TextBox`, so it does not have a `Formula` property to set. Instead, I ended up looping through all the textboxes to find the right one, then set its `Formula`. Is there a better way to do this?

```
Sub insertTextBoxWithFormula()
    Set newTextBox = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 200, 200, 150, 150)
    newTextBox.Name = "New TextBox"
    'newTextBox.Formula = "=$A$1" 'This is what I wanted to do

    'This is what I did instead
    For Each CurrentTextBox In ActiveSheet.TextBoxes
        If CurrentTextBox.Name = "New TextBox" Then
            CurrentTextBox.Formula = "=B3"
            CurrentTextBox.Name = "Finished TextBox"
        End If
    Next CurrentTextBox
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can index the TextBoxes collection using the name of the control. So your example can be abbreviated to:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 200, 200, 150, 150).Name = "New TextBox"
ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("New TextBox").Formula = "=$B$3"
```

Answer (score 2):

Or this:

```
Dim newshp As Shape
Dim newtb As TextBox

Set newshp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox _
    (msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 200, 200, 150, 150)
Set newtb = newshp.OLEFormat.Object
newtb.Formula = "$A$1"
```