# Create TextBox for every row in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find a VBA code which would iterate through rows in a specific column of a table and create a TextBox for each iterated row and set it equal to the value of that cell.

The code from here [Insert a TextBox and set the formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772309/insert-a-textbox-and-set-the-formula) does work to create one text box, but I need to modify it so that it iterates through the entire column.

I tried to make a loop like this:

```
Sub addTextBox()

Dim newshp As Shape
Dim newtb As TextBox
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  

Set newshp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.addTextBox _
    (msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 200, 80)
Set newtb = newshp.OLEFormat.Object
newtb.Formula = "Cells.Item(i, 6)"

Next i

End Sub
```

So, `newtb.Formula = "Cells.Item(i, 6)"` - this is where I have the problem; apparently `.Formula` can only refer to a static cell.

I would really appreciate any tips on how to make this looping correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Formula` should be an Excel formula.  So you need to change `"Cells.Item(i, 6)"` to `"=F" & i`.

```
Sub addTextBox()

    Dim newshp As Shape
    Dim newtb As TextBox
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set newshp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.addTextBox _
            (msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 200, 80)
        Set newtb = newshp.OLEFormat.Object
        newtb.Formula = "=F" & i

    Next i

End Sub
```

This will fix your immediate problem, but you will then need to work out where you want the TextBoxes placed - at the moment you are placing them all on top of each other.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on how .Formula operates, makes perfect sense :) And yes, I am aware that the TextBoxes are placed on top of each other, I am just trying to solve one thing at a time. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place them in column G and fit completely within the cells, you may try something like this...

```
Sub addTextBox()

    Dim newshp As Shape
    Dim newtb As TextBox
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim vLeft, vTop, vWidth, vHeight

    For i = 1 To Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set cell = Range("G" & i)
        With cell
            vLeft = .Left
            vTop = .Top
            vWidth = .Width
            vHeight = .Height
        End With
        Set newshp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.addTextBox _
            (msoTextOrientationHorizontal, vLeft, vTop, vWidth, vHeight)
        Set newtb = newshp.OLEFormat.Object
        newtb.Formula = "=F" & i

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, I did not specify where I want the TextBoxes to appear, because I still have to do my research first :)